# Почему коллекция заданная как <? super Number> может принять в себя Double, в то время как <? extends Number> не может?

Tags: коллекции, generics, полиморфизм, wildcards

Коллеги, такой код у меня работает:

```
 ArrayList<? super Number> arL = new ArrayList<>(); //Ограничение снизу
        arL.add(23.3f);
        arL.add(23d);
        arL.add(32);
        for(Object o : arL){
            System.out.println(o + " " + o.getClass());
        }
```

**Output:**

23.3 class java.lang.Float

23.0 class java.lang.Double

32 class java.lang.Integer

А код, который ограничивает сверху добавляемые типы - не работает.

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> arL = new ArrayList<>(); //Ограничение сверху
        arL.add(23.3f);
        arL.add(23d);
        arL.add(32);
        for(Object o : arL){
            System.out.println(o + " " + o.getClass());
        }
```

Я проверил на независимом ресурсе - компилятор там тоже заругался на второй код и съел легко первый. Запись `<? extends Number>` я понимаю как ***"прими в коллекцию Number и\или его подтипы"***. `Integer`, `Double` и `Float` унаследованы от `Number`. Значит они должны лететь в эту коллекцию (№2) легко и непринужденно. С другой стороны `<? super Number>` я понимаю как ***"прими в коллекцию Number и\или его супертипы"***. Но `Double`, `Float` и `Integer` не являются супертипами по отношению к `Number`. Понятное дело, что при добавлении этих переменных в коллекцию №1 должна появится ошибка компилляции. Её - нет. То есть, компилятор ведет себя с точностью наоборот.

**Вопрос:** чем объясняется наблюдаемое поведение?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, это нетривиальные особенности wildcard дженериков в Java:

1. wildcard `? extends` позволяют только читать из коллекции (но не писать в неё), отличие от wildcard `? super`;
2. wildcard `? super` позволяет только писать в коллекцию (но не читать из неё), в отличие от wildcard `? extends`.

Таким образом, из одного типа wildcard можно только читать, а в другой можно только писать.
Исключением является возможность записи `null` в `? extends` и возможность чтения `Object` из `? super`.

Подробнее смотрите [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/sberbank/blog/416413/).

Comment: А почему тогда тот, в который можно писать (super) принимает типы, которые не являются супертипами к Number? Вы говорите что super не позволяет читать. Я пишу `System.out.println(arL.get(0));` Всё компилится. Удивительно

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, тут дело в том, что, на самом деле, при описании коллекции с wildcard `? super Number`: 1. имеется строго одно требование к записи: возможность записи только `Number` (включая любые типы, приводимые к нему), т.е. любой его родительский тип (например, `Object`) уже писать нельзя, т.к. он неявным образом неприводим к `Number`; 2. невозможность присвоить в переменную с данным типом коллекцию, тип элементов которой строго не удовлетворяет этому логическому условию (например, так нельзя: `Collection<? super Number> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();`).

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, насколько я понял ваш вопрос, ответ на него кроется во втором пункте моего комментария выше. Тем не менее, я абсолютно солидарен с тем, что это крайне неочевидно и странно с точки зрения разработчика (ровно как и то, что я указал в ответе). Более того, реализация generic'ов/template'ов в языках программирования совсем нетривиальная задача, вызывающая много вопросов (в плюсах, например, template'ы сделаны совсем иначе, а в Go все еще не добавили их поддержку из-за отсутствия в их сообществе консенсуса в вопросах схожих тонкостей при реализации).